# How can I run multiple versions of the same build in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

TL/DR: Can I use `.env` file variables in docker-compose's `environment` directives?

---

I have a `Dockerfile` which uses the `ARG` variable to copy files based on an environment variable.

In my `docker-compose` I want to run two versions of this container with different configuration.

Is there a way where I can set different filepaths in a single `.env` file and have it build twice, like the example below?

Or is there a smarter way to accomplish this?

---

```
/
/.env
/docker-compose.yml
/app
/app/Dockerfile
/version1/data
/version2/data
```

**/.env**

```
VERSION_1_PATH=./version1/data
VERSION_2_PATH=./version2/data
```

**/app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

ARG APP_PATH             # pull this environment variable
COPY $APP_PATH /var/app/ # use it to copy source to the same generic destination
```

**/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  version1:
    build: ./app
    container_name: version1
    env_file: 
      - '.env'
    environment:
      APP_PATH: ${VERSION_1_PATH}

  version2:
    build: ./app
    container_name: version2
    env_file: 
      - '.env'
    environment:
      APP_PATH: ${VERSION_2_PATH}
```

Comment: Is this setting build-time options (something like `./configure` flags with different sets of included libraries), or runtime configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `args` in compose file when to define build, something like follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  version1:
    build:
      context: ./app
      args:
        - APP_PATH=${VERSION_1_PATH}

  version2:
    build:
      context: ./app
      args:
        - APP_PATH=${VERSION_2_PATH}
```

And no need to define `.env` in `env_file` if just want it be used in build as `.env` could default be used in `docker-compose.yml`. And, `environment` also not for `build`, it's for `running container`.

One [example](https://github.com/atline/dp_dashboard/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), FYI.